# plot graph and find maximum value

Tags: java, python, spss

I'm trying to open excel file that content two column "time and G" in java (also tried with python) and plot a graph between G Vs time. and to find at what times G is maximum & minimum. Please help me!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is too broad, please consider improving it by adding your code to demonstrate where you are getting stuck. You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to parse excel files in java and use library like [JfreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to generate graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not have too much experience with programming so I tried to create a small example. You said you want to get the data from excel, as I do not know how to read excel in python I assume you can create a csv file for your values.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from datetime import datetime

with open("pathtoyourfiel/data.csv") as f:
    #read file to a list of lines
    content = f.readlines()

    #split each line at ","
    data = [line.split(",") for line in content]
    #convert date string to datetime (assuming format is correct)
    dateStrings = [datetime.strptime(d[0], "%d %b %Y") for d in data]
    #convert datetime to matplotlib.date
    dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dateStrings)

    #extract G value from split list, cast to int
    g = [int(d[1]) for d in data]

    #get max and min
    maxValue = max(g)
    minValue = min(g)
    #get the date at the index of max/min
    maxDate = dateStrings[g.index(maxValue)]
    minDate = dateStrings[g.index(minValue)]

    #set formatter for the date on the x axis
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
    plt.plot(dates, g)
    plt.show()
```

where my data looks like this:
15 Jun 2015,14
24 Jul 2015,1
30 Oct 2015,5

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Aracurunir, i will try this now!!!